# How to run multiple testcases from a suite and use tags for excluding some from a csv file

Tags: python, csv, robotframework

I am trying to consolidate all the tags into 1 single csv file of all the testcases from all the suites and with this when i run on multiple versions based on the csv file(testfile to version exclusion mapping) want to exclude some of testcases. Can someone help me with this.

Example :
test1.robot should map to csv file for force tags EXCLUDEIN_1
test2.robot should map to csv file for force tags EXCLUDEIN_2
test3.robot should map to csv file for force tags EXCLUDEIN_2

Now when i run this suite in version 1 -exclude EXCLUDEIN_1 this should run
CSV File :
Testcase,EXCLUDEIN_1,EXCLUDEIN_2
test1.robot,Y,N
test2.robot,N,Y
test2.robot,N,Y

[Csv file example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2UuWk.png)

Comment: Hi Alex, I tried the datadriven method by adding the csv and library in the script but since this problem is related to skipping testfiles in a suite or multiple suites, i am stuck with the dilemma of how to crack this. I am relatively new to Robot framework so trying to understand the method or algo to get this.

Comment: Please edit your question to include a code block and/or error message in the body of question. [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). Using images for this has [numerous disadvantages]